# Chanceling two definite integrals, that are same, but with different limits

Tags: integration, definite-integrals

I have some stupid question. I am doing some assingment, and I have reached so far:
$$
\int_{T/4}^0 \frac{4t}{T}~dt-\int_{T/4}^{T/2} \frac{4t}{T}~dt\\
$$
I see that this two integrals are the same. Is it possible that I just chancel them out.

Thanks

Comment: What is $T$? The period??

Comment: Yes. T is period.I am doing some assingment, where I need to calculate RMS of voltage wavelenght.

Comment: The two integrals are not the same, because the limits of integration are not the same. You mean to say that the *integrands* of the two integrals are the same.

Comment: Well @DavidH : the two integrals aren't the same, true, but **not** because the integrals' limits are different.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

$$
\int_{T/4}^0 - \int_{T/4}^{T/2} \quad = \quad \int_{T/4}^0 + \int^{T/4}_{T/2} \quad = \quad \int_{T/2}^0
$$

In general,
$$
\int_a^b+\int_b^c=\int_a^c.
$$

Answer (score 2):

$$\begin{align*}\int\limits_{T/4}^0\frac{4t}Tdt&=\left.\frac2Tt^2\right|_{T/4}^0=-\frac2T\frac{T^2}{16}=-\frac T8\\\int\limits_{T/2}^{T/4}\frac{4t}Tdt&=\left.\frac2Tt^2\right|_{T/2}^{T/4}=\frac2T\left(\frac{T^2}{16}-\frac{T^2}4\right)=-\frac{3T}8\end{align*}$$

...so how are these two integrals the same?

Comment: I think this answer misses the point of the question.  But maybe I've misunderstood the question as well.

Comment: I wouldn't be surprised, @MichaelHardy : the way so many people here writes their questions...